# How to avoid "invalid lexical value" while adding empty nodes

Tags: xquery

```
let $a := <product>
<p1>100</p1>
<p2>100</p2>
<p3/>
</product>
for $i in $a 
return $i/p1 + $i/p2 + $i/p3
```

Why do i get invalid lexical value here when i expect the sum to be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line `return $i/p1 + $i/p2 + $i/p3` is evaluated as `return xs:double($i/p1) + xs:double($i/p2) + xs:double($i/p3)`. This works for `p1` and `p2`, but not `p3`:

```
  xs:double($i/p3) = xs:double(<p3/>)
                   = xs:double(xs:untypedAtomic(''))  (: atomization :)
                   = xs:double('')
```

Since `+` returns the empty sequence `()` if one of its arguments is the empty sequence, your approach would not have worked either way. You can use [`fn:sum($sequence)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-xpath-functions-30-20130521/#func-sum) instead, summing over the text nodes inside the elements:

```
let $a :=
  <product>
    <p1>100</p1>
    <p2>100</p2>
    <p3/>
  </product>
for $i in $a 
return sum(($i/p1/text(), $i/p2/text(), $i/p3/text()))
```

The last line can even be shortened to:

```
return sum($i/(p1, p2, p3)/text())
```

Comment: Thanks, that did help me in understanding the difference